# Linux Users adding to Directory

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, sudo, linux-mint

I have to create a shared folder under a directory, after that I have to create 2 users with their equally named home directories. It is required that the user can use the sudo command and both users should be able to edit each other's documents in the shared folder.

Can someone help me out with this? or give me the code, I tried adding users to the directory and stuff but I am stuck and also don't really understand the full exercise.

thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the shared directory and common group

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/test
$ sudo groupadd test
```

Add the two user to the group

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G test user1
$ sudo usermod -a -G test user2
```

Set the permission to directory

```
$ sudo chgrp -R project /var/test/
$ sudo chmod -R 2775 /var/test/
```